# How to add custom fee to cart summary on click

Tags: magento2, checkout, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-checkout

I want to add a custom fee to the cart summary when the checkbox is check and remove when unchecked and also adjusting the order total with each checkbox change. How can I achieve this?
[image: example order summary]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same but on the checkout summary. I hope this can help you. since my checkout is one step checkout because i'm using a template I have decided to create a new step

To have our values dynamically, I created the fields in the admin `etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="config_bag_checkout" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Configuration</label>
            <tab>xxxxxxxx</tab>
            <resource>xxxxxxxx::erp</resource>
            <group id="customfee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Bag Fee Settings</label>
                <field id="status" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="bagfee_amount" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Bag Fee Amount</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="minimum_order_amount" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Minimum Order Amount</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Greaterthan or equal to]]></comment>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Then create a helper to get the data from the admin `Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper {
    /**
     * Bag fee config path
     */
    const CONFIG_CUSTOM_IS_ENABLED = 'config_bag_checkout/customfee/status';
    const CONFIG_CUSTOM_FEE = 'config_bag_checkout/customfee/bagfee_amount';
    const CONFIG_MINIMUM_ORDER_AMOUNT = 'config_bag_checkout/customfee/minimum_order_amount';

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isModuleEnabled() {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $isEnabled = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CUSTOM_IS_ENABLED, $storeScope);
        return $isEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Get bag fee
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBagFee() {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $fee = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CUSTOM_FEE, $storeScope);
        return $fee;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMinimumOrderAmount() {
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $MinimumOrderAmount = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_MINIMUM_ORDER_AMOUNT, $storeScope);
        return $MinimumOrderAmount;
    }
}
```

To trigger the class that is in charge of updating the prices we must create a `sales.xml` file inside etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="customfee" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Total\Customfee" sort_order="150"/>
        </group>  
    </section>
</config>
```

Then create the file `Model/Total/Customfee.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Total;

class Customfee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal {
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $dataHelper;

   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper
    ) {
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    }

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

        $data = [];
        $bssData = $quote->getBssCustomfield();
        if ($bssData) {
            $data = json_decode($bssData);
        }
        if (isset($data->bag_option) && $data->bag_option === "true") {
            $bagPrice = $this->dataHelper->getBagFee();
            $minimumOrderAmount = $this->dataHelper->getMinimumOrderAmount();
            $bagFee = $total->getBaseSubtotal() <= $minimumOrderAmount ? $this->dataHelper->getBagFee(): 0;

            $total->setTotalAmount('customfee', $bagFee);
            $total->setBaseTotalAmount('customfee', $bagFee);
    
            $total->setCustomFee($bagFee);
    
            $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal());
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());
        } else {
            $bagFee = 0;
            $total->setTotalAmount('customfee', $bagFee);
            $total->setBaseTotalAmount('customfee', $bagFee);
    
            $total->setCustomFee($bagFee);
    
            $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal());
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());
        }

        return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {
        return [
            'code' => 'customfee',
            'title' => 'Custom Fee',
            'value' => $this->dataHelper->getBagFee(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel() {
        return __('Custom Fee');
    }
}
```

In my case I have installed a bss module called Checkout Custom Field this is how I validate if the user has already checked the box or not but you can replace this to use a `checkoutSession` instead of my implementation. any will work, the important thing is to know when the box is checked or unchecked to apply the fee.

Now we need to create a controller, this is called when the user selects the checkbox to save the value.

`etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customFee" id="customFee">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`Controller/Index/Index.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\MOdule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Index extends Action {
    private     $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
    protected   $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $cartRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context  $context,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
    ) {
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   


    public function execute() {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        if (!$post) {
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        try {
            $maskedQuoteId = $post['quote_id'];
            $customFeeCheck = $post['enable_custom_fee'];
            $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($maskedQuoteId, 'masked_id');
            $quoteId = $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();

            $quote = $this->cartRepository->get($quoteId);
            $quote->setBssCustomfield(json_encode(["bag_option" => $customFeeCheck]));
            $quote->save();
            return $result->setData(['success' => $quote->getData()]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $result->setData(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

This controller receives two attributes the quoteId and whether the field is checked or unchecked. i use the quote.

In my case i use the quote because there is the information of the purchase and I set the field if it is check or not. here there are two ways to set the information here, do not use the quote and use a `checkoutSession` or see what information you have in the quote that you can set and then use it in the `Model/Total/Customfee.php`. to know which data you have on the quote do this `$quote->getData()`(you can see if you can reuse something or not)

Now let's dig into the UI As I mentioned before, I've created a new step for my input check box

file `/view/frontend/web/js/view/bag-step.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function ($, ko, Component, stepNavigator, quote, totals, totalsDefaultProvider, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    var bagPrice = window.checkoutConfig.bagFeeSettings.fee_amount;
    var minimumFee = window.checkoutConfig.bagFeeSettings.minimum_order_amount;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/bag-step'
        },
        stepCode: 'bag',
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomFeeCheck: ko.observable(false),
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var self = this;
            
            if (!parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.bagFeeSettings.show_hide_block)) {
                $(".checkout-bag-step.hoverable").hide();
            }
            
            var bss_customfield = JSON.parse(window.checkoutConfig.quoteData.bss_customfield)
            if (bss_customfield && bss_customfield.bag_option === 'true') {
                this.isCustomFeeCheck(true);
            }


            totals.totals.subscribe(function(data) {
                if (data.base_subtotal <= minimumFee) {
                    self.getFeeAmount(priceUtils.formatPrice(bagPrice, quote.getPriceFormat()));
                } else {
                    self.getFeeAmount(priceUtils.formatPrice(0, quote.getPriceFormat()));
                }
            });

            return this;
        },
        getFeeAmount: ko.observable(priceUtils.formatPrice(bagPrice, quote.getPriceFormat())),
        getMinimumFee: priceUtils.formatPrice(minimumFee, quote.getPriceFormat()),
        handleCheckbox: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: `/${checkoutConfig.storeCode}/customFee/index/index`,
                method: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    totals.isLoading(true);
                },
                data: {
                    quote_id: quote.getQuoteId(),
                    enable_custom_fee: this.isCustomFeeCheck(),
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                }
            }).always(function() {
                totals.isLoading(false);
            });
            
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Take a look to the `handleCheckbox` method, there is the key:

1. We call the controller we have just created.
2. The controller set the data
3. onSuccess call `totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());`
4. `estimateTotals` trigger the `Model/Total/Customfee.php` file
5. `Customfee.php` file validates whether the box is checked or unchecked `if (isset($data->bag_option) && $data->bag_option === "true") {` base on that applies the fee or not
6. Magento automatically updates prices in the checkout summary

Please note that I have a lot of bss dependencies but you can replace this with a session hope this helps.

[image]